# Finding complex roots

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

**Problem**

Find the roots of $$z^3 = -1 - i$$

And calculate $$ \sqrt[3]{-1-i}$$

I'm looking at the solution outlined in my book but I'm having problems understanding it.

I can find the length and argument of $$-1-i$$ but then what? I guess the length is $$\sqrt{2}$$ and $$Arg(z^3) = \frac{3 \pi}{2}$$ My book says the argument is $$\frac{-3 \pi}{4}$$ though, not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z = re^{i \theta}$. Then it follows $r = (2)^{1/6}$. Divide out $r$ to get $e^{i 3\theta} = e^{-i \frac{3 \pi}4} $. (The angle follows from basic right triangle stuff). Now just set $3 \theta = -3 \pi/4$ and find the three angles from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=-1-i$ where real $r>0$ and $\pi<\theta\le\pi$

we have $\displaystyle r\cos\theta=r\sin\theta=-1\implies r^2=(r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2=(-1)^2+(-1)^2=2$

$\displaystyle\implies \cos\theta=\sin\theta=-\frac1{\sqrt2}<0$ so $\theta$ lies in the third Quadrant

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), $\theta=\arctan\left(\dfrac{-1}{-1}\right)-\pi=\dfrac\pi4-\pi$

Now use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Applications)

Comment: I do:

$$r( \cos \theta + \sin \theta) = -1 -i$$

$$=r \cos \theta + r i \sin \theta = -1 -i$$

$$=r \cos \theta = -1 -i -i r \sin \theta$$

How do you get your result? And why $$ \pi < \theta \leq \pi$$?? That means that $ \theta = \pi$ according to squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Paze, $$a+ib=c+id\implies a=c,b=d$$